# document.ready not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is NOT a case of not having jQuery loaded, but I do feel like I'm missing something else that's simple... On this staging site: https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/orders, once the page finishes loading, the "Camping & backpacking" should be auto-selected.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  console.log("about to trigger initial click")
  $(".category-selector[data-id='"+gon.category_to_start+"']").click()
})
```

It's definitely not happening. Any thoughts? The only thing that I can think of is that the `category-selector`s are interpolated from Ruby, see view code below, so maybe that's causing it?

```
<div class="row">
   <% @item_categories.each do |ic| %>
      <div class="col-xs-6 category-box">
          <div class="row category-row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 table-display category-selector text-center" data-id="<%=ic.id%>">
                  <span class="labeler-response table-cell-display">
                     <%= ic.name %>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**A little bit more info.**

The `console.log` in the code is not triggered, and `gon.category_to_start` is defined. ALL of the other jquery on the page is working perfectly.

On this page, it is loading the `application.js` and a separate `orders/new.js` that contains the code in question. It loads jquery first, then `application.js` then `new.js`. For argument's sake, I just tried to load the code snippet into `application.js` and it didn't work there either. This works fine in local server.

Comment: @ihemant360 How does that help? adding a `;` there is completely optional and does not change the code functionality at all.

Comment: add jquery library script first then your custom jquery script in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) (default if you setup a rails project), you should use `page:load` as an event.

```
$(document).on("page:load", function() {
  console.log("about to trigger initial click");
  $(".category-selector[data-id='"+gon.category_to_start+"']").click();
});
```

**NOTE**:

If you're in production mode, please make sure that you run `bin/rake assets:precompile` to keep your assets up-to-date.

Comment: I'm not using turbolinks, I tried this anyway, sadly didn't work

Comment: @james can you please post your `application.js` to the question? I can't see the code you posted in the applicaiton.js file that's on the website, so maybe it's a problem with precompiling or badly including this bunch of code

Comment: I can see the online application.js, I want the source code of application.js. Please edit

Comment: OMG I JUST RE-READ YOUR COMMENT AND I FORGOT TO PRECOMPILE.... it's after midnight and I am 10000% done, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with this line

```
$(".category-selector[data-id='"+gon.category_to_start+"']").click()
```

There is no reference to `gon.category_to_start` so probably `data-id` is getting some undefined value.

Also you can check if the `console.log` is logging any value

> "Camping & backpacking" should be auto-selected.

But I am seeing `category-selector` is on a `div` element. Do you mena to select the div, since auto-selection works on checkbox or radio button

Comment: `gon.category_to_start` is defined; if you type it into the console, you'll see that it returns 1. My `console.log` is not working, but all the other jQuery on the page works

Answer (score 0):

Why include the data-id in the selector?
You can $('.classname').trigger.('click') on document ready

Answer (score 0):

facepalm answer: precompile assets

Comment: Please be more elaborate in what was the actual issue.